# Break out of the each method in Symfony's DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I am trying to filter through the specific element and then once the text is found, I want to record the position and break out of the `each` method.  But I cannot break out of it I get the PHP error `Cannot break/continue 2 levels`

Here's the current code I'm working with:

```
$crawler->filter('#title')->each(function ($node) use ($new_text, $new_place, $place, $number) {

    // If number is found, record its place
    if (strpos($node->text(), $number) !== false) {
        $new_place = $place;
        $new_text = $node->text();
        break;
    }

    $place++;
});
```

Comment: You can try use `return $new_text;` or refactoring your code and write this in variable `$cr = $crawler->filter('#blablabla')` and check each in foreach instruction `foreach($cr as $_cr) {  }`

Comment: Thanks @Naumov.  I guess the `foreach` will work.  I'm not sure if there's any better way of doing it, but this should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1 - you are attempting to break from within an if-statement.

Issue #2 - your anonymous function does not actually return any values.

> The anonymous function receives the node (as a Crawler) and the position as arguments. The result is an array of values returned by the anonymous function calls.

from [Symfony DomCrawler Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values)

Edit: If you are using this to search for the nth element from within the list, you will want to switch to using xpath.